# Sql Server and performance of conditional left outer joins

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, left-join

I have a table that can link out to several other tables depending on certain conditions. Please consider the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @someFlag nvarchar(1) = 'B'

select COUNT(SL_A.ID) + COUNT(SL_B.ID) + COUNT(SL_C.ID) as TotalLinks
from Customers C
left outer join SomeLookupA SL_A on
    @someFlag = 'A'
    AND C.SomeLookupAId = SL_A.ID
left outer join SomeLookupB SL_B on
    @someFlag = 'B'
    AND C.SomeLookupBId = SL_B.ID
left outer join SomeLookupC SL_C on
    @someFlag = 'C'
    AND C.SomeLookupCId = SL_C.ID
```

As you can see, as @someFlag is set to 'B' only the second left outer join will return results because of the `@someFlag = '<?>'` condition on each join.

Now obviously I could equally split this SQL into 3 separate statements which would run in a conditional block:

```
if (@someFlag = 'A')
begin
    select COUNT(SL_A.ID) as TotalLinks
    from Customers C
    left outer join SomeLookupA SL_A on
        @someFlag = 'A'
        AND C.SomeLookupAId = SL_A.ID
end
else if (@someFlag = 'B')
... etc.... etc...
```

I personally prefer the first approach as it is more succinct.

My question is, **will the SQL Server engine will optimise out the redundant left joins and will the first approach generally perform just as well as the second approach?**

Comment: It took me ~5 minutes to re-write your query to a database I have sitting here, turn on "Include Actual Execution Plan", run the query, and then inspect the plan, to determine that (in this case) No. Seems like something you could have tried yourself.

Comment: Fair comment, Damien. However, I thought that this approach of using conditional outer joins may throw up some interesting answers / approaches to the problem of linking out to tables in a conditional manner and therefore it was worth posting on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. Thought I may as well answer my own question in case anyone else ever stumbles across this in the future.

It would appear that using conditional outer joins as I have shown above, **do not perform as well** as the second 'non-conditional' approach. The SQL Server engine still expends some processing time on these joins even though they can't return additional results. You can see this by constructing a query and turning on the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option as suggested above in the comments.

**TL;DR; The second approach is faster.**